# Updating data in modal without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have been struggling on an issue about retrieving some data in a modal opened dynamically in my application.

### Explanation

I'm using codeIgniter for the back-end of my application, so basically I've got a method in my controller used to send data to my view :

```
 public function load_list() {

        $this->load->model(array('my_model'));
        $this->load->helper(array('my_helper'));
        $this->lang->load(array('my_lang_file'));

        $user = get_user();
        $this->base_data['user'] = $user;
        if (!$user['auth']) {
            display_404($this->base_data);
            return;
        }

        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $array_data = array();

        $my_table_data = $this->table->get($id);
        $array_data[0] = array(
            'name' => $my_table_data->get_name(),
            'content' => $my_table_data->get_content()
        );

        ksort($array_data);
        $data = array(          
            'key' => $array_data
        );      
        $this->base_data['my_data'] = $data;

        $this->load->view('data_list', $this->base_data);
    }
```

The view `data_list` is a list of checkboxes containing different values.

Here is a sample of code of my view :

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($my_data['array_data'] as $index=>$data) {         
    echo '<div class="data-'.$data['name'].' col-md-12 list-group" '.(($i==0)? '':'style="display:none"').'>';
    $i+=1;
    foreach ($data['content']['element'] as $name=>$content) {
        echo '<a class="list-group-item clearfix"><div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9"><input type="checkbox"  id="'.$data['name'].'-element-'.$name.'" name="'.$data['name'].'-element" value="'.$name.'"><span>&nbsp;</span>';       
        echo '</a>';
    }
    if (count($data['content']['element']) == 0) echo '<br><em>'.lang('no_element').'</em>';

    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

I'm loading this view in a modal with an ajax request in JQuery (triggered when you click on a button) :

```
$.post('/folder/controller/load_list', {
        id: id
    }, function(data) {
        $('.modal-body').html(data);
        // Here is the code to check the checkboxes already saved in my database
    }
});
```

When you click on the confirm button in the bottom right corner of the modal, it's saving in the database the element checked thanks to an other Ajax request and closing the modal.

### My problem

The problem is that when I open again my modal, my element aren't checked even if I'm storing them in a global JS object like :

```
window.data = my_data;
```

I save them in this JS object in the mean time i'm saving them in my database. And everytime i'm opening my modal i read the data of this object.
But unfortunately, everytime my modal is opened again the checkboxes aren't checked.
If I reload the page my checkboxes are checked.

### My Question

How could I update my modal without reloading the page ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Our Question: why do you have to load a view in a model?

Comment: Because I want to load the content of my modal dynamically.

Comment: It's the other way round normally & logically.

Comment: In your opinion what would have been the best way to do it ?

Comment: Create a public method in the controller to communicate with the model method, then call it in the view through ajax

Comment: Are you json_encoding the result of load_list called from the ajax?